# Oddly structured "-ba" verb

Tags: grammar, translation

Working on translating a song by hand. I'm getting stuck on this line:

`助けてくださいなんて言えればさぁ`

`助けてくださいなんて` looks like "Please help me!"

`言えればさぁ` seems like "if I ask for it."

So, does this sentence then mean, "Please help me if I ask for it" ? But that doesn't seem to fit with the "さぁ" at the end... Any hints?

Comment: [神聖かまってちゃん - ぺんてる (@1:05)](https://youtu.be/ANvDXWicuTA?t=65)

Comment: What is so odd about it?   It is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

言えれば would mean "If I could say" since the れ in there indicates the potential form. (Obviously the pronoun I could be replaced with he/she/it/whatever as appropriate in context.)

I would translate 助けてくださいなんて言えれば as "If I could say 'please help me'" or "if only I could ask for help".